# Remove duplicate records based on certain fields(email_id, role_id and dob) and based on a condition (creation_date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have table named as `Customer` which contains duplicate records based on some fields.
**Customer Table:**
cust_id
email_id
role_id
dob
creation_date

**Data** in Customer Table is as below:

```
cust_id  email_id            role_id      dob        creation_date 
1        abc@abc.com            5       4/2/1966       17/09/2016   
2        abc@abc.com            5       4/2/1966       20/09/2016   
3        xyz@xyz.com            5       15/2/1991      18/09/2016  
4        xyz@xyz.com            5       15/2/1991      21/09/2016  
5        pqr@pqr.com            5       16/2/1985      30/09/2016   
6        pqr@pqr.com            5       16/2/1985      05/11/2016 
7        pqr@pqr.com            5       16/2/1985      04/11/2016
```

The email_id, role_id and dob are same(**duplicate**) for 2 or more records as in the above table.

I want **two** different queries that will result as below:

```
cust_id  email_id            role_id      dob        creation_date 
1        abc@abc.com            5       4/2/1966       17/09/2016     
3        xyz@xyz.com            5       15/2/1991      18/09/2016   
5        pqr@pqr.com            5       16/2/1985      30/09/2016
```

That is, remove duplicate record based on email_id, role_id and dob whose  creation_date is less than the other duplicate record.

```
cust_id  email_id            role_id      dob        creation_date   
2        abc@abc.com            5       4/2/1966       20/09/2016     
4        xyz@xyz.com            5       15/2/1991      21/09/2016   
6        pqr@pqr.com            5       16/2/1985      05/11/2016
```

That is, remove duplicate record based on email_id, role_id and dob whose  creation_date is greater than the other duplicate record.

**EDIT**: A counter question to the above problem.

Now when , I have a join on two tables named as Customer and Individual, how would I get the required results same as with above.
**Customer Table:**
cust_id
email_id
role_id
individaul_id(Foreign Key)
creation_date

**Individaul Table:**
individaul_id
dob

using the below query :

```
SELECT c.email_id,c.role_id,i.dob  FROM CUSTOMER c   
JOIN  INDIVIDUAL i on c.individaul_id=i.individaul_id     
GROUP BY c.email_id,c.role_id,i.dob     
Having count(*) >=2
```

I'm using **MSSQL server 2012** database.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have too much reputation to not know the fact that SO is not a code writing service and you need to show what you have already tried.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, yes. but now i'm in bit hurry it's a production issue. any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made use of query answered by @navintb and amended it as below to remove duplicate results so as to get required output.

```
SELECT max(cust_id),c.email_id,c.role_id,i.dob,max(creation_date) FROM 
CUSTOMER c 
JOIN INDIVIDUAL i on c.individual_id=i.individual_id
GROUP BY c.email_id,c.role_id,i.dob
Having count(*) >=2
```

AND,

```
SELECT min(cust_id),c.email_id,c.role_id,i.dob,min(creation_date) FROM 
CUSTOMER c 
JOIN INDIVIDUAL i on c.individual_id=i.individual_id
GROUP BY c.email_id,c.role_id,i.dob
Having count(*) >=2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to order by creation date and filter out duplicate record

First query gives record with minimun creation date

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT cust_id,  email_id, role_id, dob, creation_date ,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY email_id, role_id, dob ORDER BY creation_date ) seq FROM customer
)
SELECT  cust_id,  email_id, role_id, dob, creation_date 
FROM cte
WHERE seq = 1
```

For max creation date same query works with ORDER BY done in descending order

```
 ;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT cust_id,  email_id, role_id, dob, creation_date ,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY email_id, role_id, dob ORDER BY creation_date DESC ) seq FROM customer
    )
    SELECT  cust_id,  email_id, role_id, dob, creation_date 
    FROM cte
    WHERE seq = 1
```

**EDIT**
For JOIN query just add join conditions to CTE expression SELECT statement

```
 ;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.cust_id,  c.email_id, c.role_id, i.dob, c.creation_date ,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.email_id, c.role_id, c.dob ORDER BY c.creation_date ) seq
FROM customer c
JOIN  INDIVIDUAL i on c.individaul_id=i.individaul_id
)
SELECT  cust_id,  email_id, role_id, dob, creation_date 
FROM cte
WHERE seq = 1
```

For max creation date same query works with ORDER BY done in descending order

```
 ;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.cust_id,  c.email_id, c.role_id, i.dob, c.creation_date ,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.email_id, c.role_id, c.dob ORDER BY c.creation_date DESC ) seq
FROM customer c
JOIN  INDIVIDUAL i on c.individaul_id=i.individaul_id
    )
    SELECT  cust_id,  email_id, role_id, dob, creation_date 
    FROM cte
    WHERE seq = 1
```

Comment: can you please have look into my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671048/remove-duplicate-records-from-join-query-based-on-certain-fieldsemail-id-role it is same but the data fetch is from join query.

Comment: Remove that question .. i am posting here .. not much change required

Comment: Ok, I have removed that question.

Comment: You have written wrongly c.mail_id in PARTITION. It should be c.email_id :-)

Comment: @RohitGaikwad Question should be edited. No where mentioned INDIVIDUAL table. Please edit the question because this answer looking like irrelevant.

Comment: @GuruprakashC, it was mentioned for another query for the above reply to solve it by join method.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad But you have removed. right?. So you should update the question :-)

Comment: @mhasan, The query was still executing, But I think its not working because I have around 120 such records and I want 60 records min 60 max. but your query gives me more than 200 records

Comment: @RohitGaikwad I guess, The records getting duplicate with INDIVIDUAL  table. Please check

Comment: @GuruprakashC, I'm getting unexpected output. please check my above comments.

Answer (score 1):

use min and max functions

```
select min(cust_id),email_id,role_id,dob,min(creation_date) from customer group by email_id,role_id,dob;

select max(cust_id),email_id,role_id,dob,max(creation_date) from customer group by email_id,role_id,dob;
```

hope it works

Comment: Thanks. The sorting is based on only `creation_date` and not on `cust_id`

Comment: can you please have a look into my new question stackoverflow.com/questions/40671048/… it is same but the data fetch is from join query?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION`. Just google it for the same.

Check this query:

```
    Declare @customer table(cust_id int, email_id varchar(200), role_id int, dob datetime, creation_date datetime)

    Insert into @customer
    values(1,'abc@abc.com',5,'04-feb-1966','17-sep-2016'),
    (2,'abc@abc.com',5,'04-feb-1966','20-sep-2016'),
    (3,'xyz@xyz.com',5,'15-feb-1991','18-sep-2016'),
    (4,'xyz@xyz.com',5,'15-feb-1991','21-sep-2016'),
    (5,'pqr@pqr.com',5,'16-feb-1985','30-sep-2016'),
    (6,'pqr@pqr.com',5,'16-feb-1985','05-nov-2016'),
    (7,'pqr@pqr.com',5,'16-feb-1985','04-nov-2016')

--using row number and partition to group data and remove duplicate
    ;with custCTE as(
    select cust_id, email_id, role_id,dob,creation_date,row_number() over(partition by email_id, role_id, dob order by creation_date ) as rnk
    from @customer
    )

    delete from @customer where cust_id in (select cust_id from custCTE where rnk <> 1)
    select * from @customer
```

Comment: thanks for this. can you please check the updated question (Edit) , it is done using join. The data already exists in db I just need that two queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
DECLARE @MainTable TABLE
(
    Cust_Id INT,
    Email_Id NVARCHAR(250),
    Role_Id INT,
    DOB DATE,
    Creation_Date DATE 
)

DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
    Cust_Id INT,
    Email_Id NVARCHAR(250),
    Role_Id INT,
    DOB DATE,
    Creation_Date DATE 
)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
    Cust_Id INT,
    Email_Id NVARCHAR(250),
    Role_Id INT,
    DOB DATE,
    Creation_Date DATE 
)

INSERT INTO @MainTable
        ( Cust_Id ,
          Email_Id ,
          Role_Id ,
          DOB ,
          Creation_Date
        )
VALUES  ( 1 , N'abc@abc.com' , 5 , '2/4/1966' , '09/17/2016' ),
        ( 2 , N'abc@abc.com' , 5 , '2/4/1966' , '09/20/2016' ),
        ( 3 , N'xyz@xyz.com' , 5 , '2/15/1991' , '09/18/2016' ),
        ( 4 , N'xyz@xyz.com' , 5 , '2/15/1991' , '09/21/2016' ),
        ( 5 , N'pqr@pqr.com' , 5 , '2/16/1985' , '09/30/2016' ),
        ( 6 ,N'pqr@pqr.com' , 5 , '2/16/1985' , '11/05/2016' ),
        ( 7 , N'pqr@pqr.com' , 5 , '2/16/1985' , '11/04/2016' )

;WITH MainTable AS (
SELECT 
    Cust_Id ,
    Email_Id ,
    Role_Id ,
    DOB ,
    Creation_Date ,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Email_Id, Role_Id, DOB ORDER BY Creation_Date) AS [Rank]
FROM @MainTable
) 
INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT 
    MainTable.Cust_Id ,
    MainTable.Email_Id ,
    MainTable.Role_Id ,
    MainTable.DOB ,
    MainTable.Creation_Date 
FROM MainTable
WHERE MainTable.[Rank] = 1

;WITH MainTable AS (
SELECT 
    Cust_Id ,
    Email_Id ,
    Role_Id ,
    DOB ,
    Creation_Date ,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Email_Id, Role_Id, DOB ORDER BY Creation_Date) AS [Rank]
FROM @MainTable
) 
INSERT INTO @Table2
SELECT 
    MainTable.Cust_Id ,
    MainTable.Email_Id ,
    MainTable.Role_Id ,
    MainTable.DOB ,
    MainTable.Creation_Date 
FROM MainTable
WHERE MainTable.[Rank] <> 1


SELECT * FROM @MainTable ORDER BY Cust_Id
SELECT * FROM @Table1 ORDER BY Cust_Id
SELECT * FROM @Table2 ORDER BY Cust_Id
```

Basically such problems can be handled in better way by using sql server windows functions. Window functions are more functional in sql server 2012 with add functionality. So, the above code will work fine in MSSQL 2012.